# FFMPEG mkv to mp4 conversion lacks audio in HTML5 player

Tags: html, audio, video, ffmpeg

I used `ffmpeg` to convert an `mkv` file to `mp4` using this command line:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c copy file-1.mp4
```

The resulting `mp4` plays fine (video and audio) on `Linux Mint's Xplayer`. But after uploading file-1, it played with no audio. So I uploaded another `mp4` file-2, one I didn't have to convert, and it plays both video and audio without a problem. So whatever's going on with `file-1` seems to be with my use of `ffmpeg`.

The player I'm using is called `afterglow`. But the `HTML5 player` handles these two files the same way: file-1 & file-2

Does anyone know why the `ffmpeg` converted file is soundless when played online? Is there a different conversion command that ensures converted `mkv files` will play with sound by online players?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard - Do you need the frame-by-frame output? Or just the initial start up and ending, leaving out the frame conversion?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard - I've updated my post with a link to conversion output. Again, I'm only losing sound when an online player's used. The file provides sound when played from my hard drive.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I see several issues:

1. The input has DTS audio. Although it is supported in MP4 I guess it doesn't work with HTML5. You'll have to convert to AAC. Add `-c:a aac` after the `-c copy`.
2. Your `ffmpeg` is old. The FFmpeg AAC encoder had improvements that your version is missing. Avoid any other potential issues by [downloading a recent version](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html).
3. Add `-movflags +faststart`. This will move some info in the file after encoding so it can begin playback quicker; otherwise it will have to download the whole video before playing.

Example command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c copy -c:a aac -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Comment: So, this is the correct command: ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c copy -c:a aac -movflags +faststart file-1.mp4 ? I'll fetch the newer ffmpeg, too.

Comment: @fmc Yes (2+ years later).