# FFMpeg doesnt insert sound to converted media files

Tags: ffmpeg, media

I am new at FFMpeg. I use this code to convert media files to WebM and MP4 formats:

(It's php)

```
  // MP4
    $video_mp4 = $output_name . '.mp4';
    exec($ffmpeg . ' -i "' . $uploaded_file . '" -c:v libx264 -an "./converted/' . $video_mp4 . '" -y 1>convert.txt 2>&1', $output, $convert_status['mp4']);

    // Debug
     echo '<pre>' . print_r($output, 1) . ' </pre>';

    // WebM
    $video_webm = $output_name . '.webm';
    exec($ffmpeg . ' -i "' . $uploaded_file . '" -c:v libvpx -c:a libvorbis -an "./converted/' . $video_webm . '" -y 1>convert.txt 2>&1', $output, $convert_status['webm']);

    // Debug
```

The code converts media files but the converted media files (they are in MP4 and WebM formats) haven't any sound.

Can you write a true convert command if my code is false?

Also I wonder about -movflags +faststart commands. What are they, can you explain?

I added "aac" command to WebM traslator command as how did "llogan"
say in an answer which is on below link:

[FFMPEG mkv to mp4 conversion lacks audio in HTML5 player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46456692/ffmpeg-mkv-to-mp4-conversion-lacks-audio-in-html5-player)

but after I added the command, my media files haven't been converted.

Comment: improved readability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the converted media files ( they are in MP4 and WebM formats ) hasnt any sound.

You are using the `-an` option which disables audio output. Remove `-an`.

> Also I wonder that -movflags +faststart commands.What are thet, can you explain?

`-movflags +faststart` relocates some info after encoding is finished. It moves the info from the end of the file to the beginning of the file. The info can only be made once encoding is finished, so that is why it isn't made immediately at the start. This info is required for playback, so this option is useful if viewers will watch via progressive download. Otherwise they would have to download the video completely before it can start playing. It is only useful for MP4/M4A/M4V/MOV.

Comment: Do you know idea about below question or have any html5player suggestion?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60974133/overlay-text-not-visible-when-viewing-fullscreen-video

Comment: @In-my-country-we-dont-use-name Sorry, I don't have an answer for that.